# PS3 "roaming" profile?

Tags: ps3

We're upgrading our 3 aging PS2's at work to PS3's today, to get GT5 and other games, and seeing as I have a PS3 at home, a few questions come to mind:

- Can we create profiles for the people that will play and have them exist on all the 3 PS3's?
- Can I take my home profile and use it on those 3 PS3?
- Would I need to keep it on a USB stick (assuming that is even possible)?
- Can I "download" it onto the machines?
- What about ranks in games such as Call of Duty Black Ops, would that follow my profile or be locked to one of the machines?

Basically I would like to play with my own profile regardless of which of those 3 PS3's I'm sitting at, and I would guess that many at work would want their own profile to play with too, without that being locked to a single PS3 either. For instance, it wouldn't be much fun if the profile of two of the players that want to play together only exists on the same PS3.

Hope I was being clear what I wanted.

Comment: Notes that in most games is the main player who gets the trophies. So if I made the connection with your other topic which required multi-player games, you should possibly be on your account for them, and even if you can choose among the existing accounts on the console when you're the second or more players.

Comment: Take note of that if you put your profile on other PS3, it would be better for you to lock them to prevent other employees use it or modify certain information. You can add a password that you will be asked each time you log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Playstation Network (PSN) account can be [simultaneously associated with five PS3 machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3#Digital_rights_management). So to answer the questions:

---

> - Can we create profiles for the people that will play and have them exist on all the 3 PS3's?
> - Can I take my home profile and use it on those 3 PS3?

Yes, each person could have a user profile associated with their PSN account on each of the 3 PS3s. You would be able to use your existing home profile.

---

> - Would I need to keep it on a USB stick (assuming that is even possible)?
> - Can I "download" it onto the machines?

Information kept on the PSN servers (trophies, list of your purchases) is automatically kept in sync between PS3s using the same PSN ID (note - you would need to ensure that trophies are synced to the server by visiting the Trophies menu item in the XMB). However information kept locally (save games, downloaded files) would not be synced. I think you can transfer most saved games using a USB stick as long as you only play them with the same account.

---

> - What about ranks in games such as Call of Duty Black Ops, would that follow my profile or be locked to one of the machines?

Rankings are stored on servers and associated with your PSN ID, so should work fine, although you may need to copy your save games across in order to use the same character profile.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have a PS3 at home and share your account with this 3 machines and your personal PS3 got broken, you can buy another one and everything will be ok. But if that broke, you are screwed. Is not very likely but still.

Comment: From what I've read on some forums, if you delete your account from one of the 5 PS3 machines with your PSN ID then you can use the ID on another machine. I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 2):

Some game saves (for example GT5) prohibit copying of the game save files. In those cases your save files are not portable.

Also, all games I'm aware of will not access saves directly from anything other than the internal PS3 storage. You'll likely find the process of copying saves around to simulate portable saves to be tedious. (IMO Cloud storage of saves really should be a feature of PSN Plus)